# There is no ` install.rb ` file in the decompressed facter directory

Tags: ruby, puppet

I follow the [document](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/3.8/install_tarball.html#step-2-download-puppet-and-its-dependencies):

> Unarchive the Facter, Hiera, and Puppet tarballs, then navigate to each resulting directory and run:
>
> > sudo ruby install.rb

I download this [facter file tar.gz](https://downloads.puppetlabs.com/facter/facter-3.9.6.tar.gz), and decompress it:

```
[root@localhost facter-3.9.6]# ll
total 56
drwxr-xr-x. 2 22002 624 4096 Apr 13  2018 cmake
-rw-r--r--. 1 22002 624 6961 Apr 13  2018 CMakeLists.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 22002 624 4434 Apr 13  2018 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-xr-x. 2 22002 624   43 Apr 13  2018 exe
drwxr-xr-x. 5 22002 624   96 Apr 13  2018 ext
-rw-r--r--. 1 22002 624 5070 Apr 13  2018 Extensibility.md
drwxr-xr-x. 9 22002 624 4096 Apr 13  2018 lib
-rw-r--r--. 1 22002 624  694 Apr 13  2018 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x. 2 22002 624   44 Apr 13  2018 locales
-rw-r--r--. 1 22002 624  745 Apr 13  2018 MAINTAINERS
drwxr-xr-x. 3 22002 624   17 Apr 13  2018 man
-rw-r--r--. 1 22002 624 1404 Apr 13  2018 Rakefile
-rw-r--r--. 1 22002 624 9197 Apr 13  2018 README.md
drwxr-xr-x. 2 22002 624   46 Apr 13  2018 scripts
```

But how can I install it?

I can not install like `sudo ruby install.rb`, because there is no `install.rb` under the decompressed directory.

Comment: Have you checked out the readme file in the directory?

Comment: The document is buggy here. You have to build `facter` from scratch like any other normal C++ lib.